# how can i read the 3rd item in json response with php?

Tags: php, json, curl

I got the followin code that works fine:

PHP SCRIPT

```
$url = 'http://wannacharts.com/ch5.php';

//create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init($url);


$payload = $data;

//attach encoded JSON string to the POST fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

//set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

//return response instead of outputting
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute the POST request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close cURL resource
curl_close($ch);
```

This return this JSon:

```
{"status":200,"status-msg":"OK","data":"1234567"}
```

And i Need to echo the filed "data".

I try:

```
$result= json_decode($result,true);

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['data'];
}
```

but does not work

Comment: emmm.. `$result['data']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way you could access the data information inside the json:

```
 $json= json_decode($result,true);

 $obj = json_decode($json);
 print $obj->{'data'};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$result= json_decode($result,true);
echo $result['data'];
```

You might find it useful to `var_dump($result)` so that you can see its structure if you're unsure how JSON translates to a PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
$v = file_get_contents(utf8_encode('http://wannacharts.com/ch5.php'));
$result = json_decode($v, true);
foreach ($result as $k => $v) 
{
  print $v['data'];
}
```

Normally Json responses would be something like this:

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if you would like to select the GlossDiv title you would say

```
print $v['glossary']['GlossDiv']['title']; //prints out "S"
```

Comment: replacing `curl` with `file_get_contents` won't solve his issue since issue is not in the way of getting data

Comment: @ArtOsi yes I know, I simply provided a method to the way I would handle the response. I have edited my answer as well